# Target transformation and feature selection in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection, rfe

I am using `RFECV` for feature selection in scikit-learn. I would like to compare the result of a  simple linear model (`X,y`) with that of a log transformed model (using `X, log(y)`)

**Simple Model**:
`RFECV` and `cross_val_score` provide the same result (we need to compare the average score of cross-validation across all folds with the score of `RFECV` for all features: `0.66` = `0.66`, no problem, results are reliable)

**Log Model**:
the **Problem**: it seems that `RFECV` does not provide a way to trasnform the `y`. the scores in this case are `0.55` vs `0.53`. This is quite expected though, because I had to manually apply `np.log` to fit the data: `log_seletor = log_selector.fit(X,np.log(y))`. This r2 score is for `y = log(y)`, with no `inverse_func`, while what we need is a way to fit the model on the `log(y_train)` and calculate the score using `exp(y_test)`. Alternatively, if I try to use the `TransformedTargetRegressor`, I get the error shown in the code: *The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes*

How do I resolve the problem and make sure that the feature selection process is reliable?

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
import numpy as np

X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = linear_model.LinearRegression()
log_estimator = TransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=linear_model.LinearRegression(),
                                                func=np.log,
                                                inverse_func=np.exp)
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='r2')
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
###
# log_selector = RFECV(log_estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='r2')
# log_seletor = log_selector.fit(X,y) 
# #RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes
###
log_selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='r2')
log_seletor = log_selector.fit(X,np.log(y))

print("**Simple Model**")
print("RFECV, r2 scores: ", np.round(selector.grid_scores_,2))
scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=5)
print("cross_val, mean r2 score: ", round(np.mean(scores),2), ", same as RFECV score with all features") 
print("no of feat: ", selector.n_features_ )

print("**Log Model**")
log_scores = cross_val_score(log_estimator, X, y, cv=5)
print("RFECV, r2 scores: ", np.round(log_selector.grid_scores_,2))
print("cross_val, mean r2 score: ", round(np.mean(log_scores),2)) 
print("no of feat: ", log_selector.n_features_ )
```

**Output:**

```
**Simple Model**
RFECV, r2 scores:  [0.45 0.6  0.63 0.68 0.68 0.69 0.68 0.67 0.66 0.66]
cross_val, mean r2 score:  0.66 , same as RFECV score with all features
no of feat:  6

**Log Model**
RFECV, r2 scores:  [0.39 0.5  0.59 0.56 0.55 0.54 0.53 0.53 0.53 0.53]
cross_val, mean r2 score:  0.55
no of feat:  3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to add such properties to the `TransformedTargetRegressor`:

```
class MyTransformedTargetRegressor(TransformedTargetRegressor):
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self.regressor_.feature_importances_

    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self.regressor_.coef_
```

Then in you code, use that:

```
log_estimator = MyTransformedTargetRegressor(regressor=linear_model.LinearRegression(),
                                             func=np.log,
                                             inverse_func=np.exp)
```

Answer (score 1):

One workaround for this problem is to make sure `coef_` attribute is exposed to the feature selection module `RFECV`. So basically you need extent the `TransformedTargetRegressor` and make sure it exposes the attribute `coef_`. I have created a the child class that will extent from `TransformedTargetRegressor` and also exposes `coef_` as shown below.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_friedman1
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.compose import TransformedTargetRegressor
import numpy as np

class myestimator(TransformedTargetRegressor):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(regressor=LinearRegression(),func=np.log,inverse_func=np.exp)

    def fit(self, X, y, **kwargs):
        super().fit(X, y, **kwargs)  
        self.coef_ = self.regressor_.coef_
        return self
```

And then you can use `myestimator` to create your code as shown below:

```
X, y = make_friedman1(n_samples=50, n_features=10, random_state=0)
estimator = linear_model.LinearRegression()
log_estimator = myestimator(regressor=LinearRegression(),func=np.log,inverse_func=np.exp)

selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='r2')
selector = selector.fit(X, y)
log_selector = RFECV(log_estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='r2')
log_seletor = log_selector.fit(X,y)
```

I have run your sample code and shown the result.

> SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
print("**Simple Model**")
print("RFECV, r2 scores: ", np.round(selector.grid_scores_,2))
scores = cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, cv=5)
print("cross_val, mean r2 score: ", round(np.mean(scores),2), ", same as RFECV score with all features") 
print("no of feat: ", selector.n_features_ )

print("**Log Model**")
log_scores = cross_val_score(log_estimator, X, y, cv=5)
print("RFECV, r2 scores: ", np.round(log_selector.grid_scores_,2))
print("cross_val, mean r2 score: ", round(np.mean(log_scores),2)) 
print("no of feat: ", log_selector.n_features_ )


**Simple Model**
RFECV, r2 scores:  [0.45 0.6  0.63 0.68 0.68 0.69 0.68 0.67 0.66 0.66]
cross_val, mean r2 score:  0.66 , same as RFECV score with all features
no of feat:  6
**Log Model**
RFECV, r2 scores:  [0.41 0.51 0.59 0.59 0.58 0.56 0.54 0.53 0.55 0.55]
cross_val, mean r2 score:  0.55
no of feat:  4
```

Comment: thanks! seems to be a way to resolve it, but how would I import the modified code? RFECV itself uses RFE, so things become a bit messy.. Plus, your sample output is just a sample I assume. right? you did not actually run the code? because the numbers do not make sense. the second one should give me 0.55 at the end and not 0.66..

Comment: Instead of modifying multiple files, I have made it simpler now! you just need to replace your `rfe.py` file in your local system (can be found at /sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py) with the file that I have posted in the github gist.

Comment: thanks. that could work, but not ideal, as it will make my code non-portable and non-reproducible. Can anything else be done without touching the Scikit source?

Comment: Yeah that's a valid point, I made the necessary changes to the code. And now you don't have to worry about touching the source code and it's very easily portable and reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @Parthasarathy. I got two correct answers. Will upvote for now